# Green's function impulse

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-physics

> Solve $y''(t)-a^2y(t)=\delta(t-t'), \ y(0)=0, \ y'(0)=0, \ t'>0.$

I am not sure how to solve an equation that has $\delta(t-t')$ as a solution. The book doesn't really elaborate further than stating that it is an impulse. I am sure I can use Green's Function, since this question is in that section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to solve $y''-a^{2}y=f$ subject to $y(0)=y'(0)$, the Green function solution is
$$
      y(t)=\frac{1}{2a}\left[e^{at}\int_{0}^{t}e^{-au}f(u)\,du-e^{-at}\int_{0}^{t}e^{au}f(u)\,du\right].
$$
You can check that
$$
       y'(t) = \frac{1}{2}\left[e^{at}\int_{0}^{t}e^{-au}f(u)\,du+e^{-at}\int_{0}^{t}e^{au}f(u)\,du\right],\\
      y''(t)=\frac{a}{2}\left[e^{at}\int_{0}^{t}e^{-au}f(u)\,dt-ae^{-at}\int_{0}^{t}e^{au}f(u)\,du\right]+f(t).
$$
That is, $y''-a^{2}y=f$. And it is easy to check that $y(0)=y'(0)=0$ from the explict expressions given above for $y$, $y'$.

Let $f(u)=\delta(u-t')$. Then 
$$
\begin{align}
            y(t) & = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
                               0, & 0 \le t < t',\\
                               \frac{1}{2a}[e^{at}e^{-at'}-e^{-at}e^{at'}] & t > t'
                          \end{array}\right. \\
      & = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
                               0, & 0 \le t < t',\\
                               \frac{1}{a}\sinh(a(t-t')) & t > t'
                          \end{array}\right. .
\end{align}
$$
For problems such as this one, you can approximate $\delta(t-t')$ as a square pulse centered at $t'$ whose integral is $1$. So, for example, the pulse could be concentrated in the time interval $t'-\frac{1}{2n} \le t \le t'+\frac{1}{2n}$ of height $n$. For large enough $n$, the length of time of pulse is immeasurably short, and the response $y$ will be as close as you want to the response given above. So, $\int \delta(t-t')f(t)\,dt = f(t')$ is as close to accurate as you want provided $f$ is continuous near $t'$ and the interval of integration includes $t'$ in its interior. And that results in a response $y(t)$ which is as close as you want to the one given above.

So the response stays at $0$ because of $y(0)=y'(0)=0$, but it immediately starts growing when you first thump it very sharply. It grows without bound because there is an unstable positive feedback. A continuous driving signal can be viewed as a succession of small thumps spaced very closely together in time whose amplitudes are given by the driving function $f$, and the response is then a superposition of these fundamental solutions.

Comment: Thank you very much! For $f(u)=\delta(u-t')$, how did you get the results of $y(t)$?

Comment: I plugged the specific $f=\delta_{t'}$ back into the original integral expression for the solution given for a general $f$. To do that, all you have to remember is that $\int_{0}^{t}G(u)\delta(u-t')\,du$ will be $0$ if $[0,t]$ does not include $t'$ and then it will be $G(t')$ once it does. This is because the $\delta$ has total area $1$ and $G$ is nearly constant and equal to $G(t')$ where the impulse is concentrated.

Comment: @Robben : You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
The differential equation is equivalent to: 
\begin{align}\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
{\rm y}''\pars{t} - a^{2}{\rm y}\pars{t} & = & 0\,,\qquad t \not= t'
\\[2mm]
\lim_{t\ \to\ t'^{+}}{\rm y}'\pars{t}
-\lim_{t\ \to\ t'^{-}}{\rm y}'\pars{t} & = & 1
\\[2mm]
{\rm y}\pars{0} = 0\,,\qquad{\rm y}'\pars{0} & = & 0
\end{array}\right.\qquad\qquad {\Large t'\ >\ 0}
\end{align}

> It's clear that $\ds{{\rm y}\pars{t}}$ vanishes out identically in $\ds{\pars{0,t'}}$. Then,
>   $$
> {\rm y}\pars{t}=\Theta\pars{t - t'}
> \bracks{{\rm A}\pars{t'}\sinh\pars{at} + {\rm B}\pars{t'}\cosh\pars{at}}
> $$ which satisfies:

\begin{align}
\left\{\begin{array}{rcrcl}
\sinh\pars{at'}{\rm A}\pars{t'} & + & \cosh\pars{at'}{\rm B}\pars{t'} & = & 0
\\[2mm]
\cosh\pars{at'}a{\rm A}\pars{t'} & + & \sinh\pars{at'}a{\rm B}\pars{t'} & = & 1 
\end{array}\right.
\end{align}

> such that
>   \begin{align}
> {\rm A}\pars{t'}&=-\,{1 \over a}\verts{%
> \begin{array}{rr}0 & \cosh\pars{at'} \\[2mm] 1 & a\sinh\pars{at'}\end{array}}
> ={\cosh\pars{at'} \over a}
> \\[5mm]
> {\rm B}\pars{t'}&=-\,{1 \over a}\verts{%
> \begin{array}{rr}\sinh\pars{at'} & 0 \\[2mm] a\cosh\pars{at'} & 1\end{array}}
> =-\,{\sinh\pars{at'} \over a}
> \end{align}

\begin{align}
&\color{#66f}{\large{\rm y}\pars{t}}
=\Theta\pars{t - t'}\bracks{{\cosh\pars{at'} \over a}\,\sinh\pars{at} - {\sinh\pars{at'} \over a}\,\cosh\pars{at}}
\\[5mm]&=\color{#66f}{\large%
\Theta\pars{t - t'}\,{\sinh\pars{a\bracks{t - t'}} \over a}
=\left\lbrace
\begin{array}{lcrcl}
0 & \mbox{if} & t & < & t'
\\[2mm]
{\sinh\pars{a\bracks{t - t'}} \over a} & \mbox{if} & t & > & t' 
\end{array}\right.}
\end{align}

> Let's check the solution:
>   \begin{align}
> \color{#c00000}{{\rm y}'\pars{t}}&
> =\delta\pars{t - t'}\,{\sinh\pars{a\bracks{t - t'}} \over a}
> +\Theta\pars{t - t'}\,{\cosh\pars{a\bracks{t - t'}}a \over a}
> \\&=\color{#c00000}{\Theta\pars{t - t'}\cosh\pars{a\bracks{t - t'}}}
> \\[5mm]
> \color{#c00000}{{\rm y}''\pars{t}}&
> =\delta\pars{t - t'}\cosh\pars{a\bracks{t - t'}}
> +\Theta\pars{t - t'}\sinh\pars{a\bracks{t - t'}}a
> \\&=\delta\pars{t - t'}
> +a^{2}\braces{\Theta\pars{t - t'}\,{\sinh\pars{a\bracks{t - t'}} \over a}}
> =\color{#c00000}{\delta\pars{t - t'} + a^{2}{\rm y}\pars{t}}
> \\[5mm]&\boxed{\quad\ds{\imp\quad{\rm y}''\pars{t} - a^{2}{\rm y}\pars{t} = \delta\pars{t - t'}}\quad}
> \\&\mbox{with}\quad
> \braces{\begin{array}{rcl}
> {\rm y}\pars{0}&=&\Theta\pars{-t'}\,{\sinh\pars{-at'} \over a} = 0
> \\[2mm]
> {\rm y}'\pars{0}&=&\Theta\pars{-t'}\cosh\pars{-at'} = 0
> \end{array}}\quad\mbox{since}\quad t' > 0.
> \end{align}

Comment: Thank you very much! It is much more clear to me now.

Comment: @Robben I'm glad it was useful for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another approach is to use the Laplace transform method.
Let $Y(s) = \mathcal{L}[y]$ then, by taking the Laplace transform of both sides and using the initial conditions, we have
$$s^2Y(s) - a^2Y(s) = e^{-t's} \implies Y(s) = \frac{e^{-t's}}{s^2 - a^2}.$$
Recall that
$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left[\frac{a}{s^2 - a^2}\right] = \sinh(at)$$
and the shifting formula gives
$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}[e^{-t's}F(s)] = f(t-t')u(t-t')$$ where $u$ is the Heaviside step function.
Thus
$$y(t) = \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left[\frac{e^{-t's}}{s^2 - a^2}\right] =\frac{1}{a}\sinh(a(t-t'))u(t-t')$$
which gives the same result as the answers by T.A.E and Felix Marin.